# Steady-state heat conduction in a cylinder with discontinuity in thermal conductivity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, bessel-functions, cylindrical-coordinates

Consider a solid cylinder of length *L* and radius *a* in which the thermal conductivity has a jump discontinuity at a point along its axis. The two
bases of the cylinder are maintained at zero temperature while the lateral surface is at a constant temperature. We wish to find the steady state temperature in the cylinder.

The problem has axial symmetry so the temperature *u* is a function only of the cylindrical coordinates(*r*,*z*). Selecting the origin of a cylindrical coordinate system at the point of discontinuity, the governing equations and boundary condition are:
$$\nabla^2u_1=0, -l_1<z<0$$
$$\nabla^2u_2=0, 0<z<l_2$$
$u_1(r,-l_1)=0,u_2(r,l_2)=0,u_1(a,z)=u_0,u_2(a,z)=u_0$

In the section of the cylinder $-l_1<z<0,$ the thermal conductivity is $k_1$ while in the other section $0<z<l_2$, the thermal conductivity is $k_2$. In addition to the above boundary conditions, we need to impose the two continuity conditions

$u_1=u_2$ and $k_1 \frac{\partial
   u_1}{\partial z}=k_2
   \frac{\partial
   u_2}{\partial z}$ at *z*=0.

Following the usual method of separation of variables and enforcing the *homogeneous* boundary conditions, we find
$$u_1(r,z)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   A_n I_0\left(\lambda _n
   r\right) \left(\cos
   \left(\lambda _n
   z\right)+\cot \left(\lambda
   _n l_1\right) \sin
   \left(\lambda _n
   z\right)\right)$$
$$u_2(r,z)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   A_n I_0\left(\lambda _n
   r\right) \left(\cos
   \left(\lambda _n
   z\right)-\cot \left(\lambda
   _n l_2\right) \sin
   \left(\lambda _n
   z\right)\right)$$
where $I_0(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of order zero of the first kind and $\lambda _n$ is the *n*th positive roots of the equation
$$k_1 \cot \left(\lambda 
   l_1\right)+k_2 \cot
   \left(\lambda  l_2\right)=0$$
Setting $u_1(a,z)=u_0$ we obtain an expansion that looks like a Fourier series but cannot directly determine the coefficients $A_n$ since we do not have an orthogonality condition. Fuththermore, setting $u_2(a,z)=u_0$ we obtain a similar situation. This posses two problems

1. How do we compute the coefficients $A_n$
2. Do the two alterenatives give the same solution

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to approach your question, but how've you been?

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem by the superposition of two harmonic functions $\tilde{u}(r,z)$ and $\hat{u}(r,z)$ where $\tilde{u}(r,z)$ vanishes on the two bases of the cylinder and assumes the value $u_0$ on the lateral surface.The function $\tilde{u}(r,z)$ (as computed below) does not satisfy the continuity requirements at the interface, so we find a harmonic function $\hat{u}(r,z)$ such that $\tilde{u}(r,z)$+$\hat{u}(r,z)$ vanishes at $z=-l_1$ and $z=l_2$, assumes the value $u_0$ on the lateral surface and satisfies the continuity conditions at $z=0$. Using separtion of variables in cylindrical coordinates, it is readily found that
$$\tilde{u_1}(r,z)=\frac{4u_0}{\pi }\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{I_0\left(\frac{(2
   n-1) \pi  r}{l_1}\right)
   \sin \left((2 n-1) \pi 
   \left(\frac{z}{l_1}+1\right
   )\right)}{I_0\left(\frac{(2
   n-1) \pi  a}{l_1}\right) (2
   n-1)}\hspace{4 mm}-l_1<z<0$$
$$\tilde{u_2}(r,z)=\frac{4u_0}{\pi }\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{I_0\left(\frac{(2
   n-1) \pi  r}{l_2}\right)
   \sin \left(\frac{(2 n-1)
   \pi 
   z}{l_2}\right)}{I_0\left(\frac{(2 n-1) \pi 
   a}{l_2}\right) (2 n-1)}\hspace{4 mm}0<z<l_2$$
It follows that
$$\frac{\partial
   \tilde{u}_1}{\partial
   z}\Bigr\rvert_{z = 0}=-\frac{4 u_0}{l_1}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{I_0\left(\frac{(2
   n-1) \pi 
   r}{l_1}\right)}{I_0\left(\frac{(2 n-1) \pi 
   a}{l_1}\right)}\doteq
   \sigma _1(r),\hspace{4 mm}\frac{\partial
   \tilde{u}_2}{\partial
   z}\Bigr\rvert_{z = 0}=\frac{4 u_0}{l_2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{I_0\left(\frac{(2
   n-1) \pi 
   r}{l_2}\right)}{I_0\left(\frac{(2 n-1) \pi 
   a}{l_2}\right)}\doteq
   \sigma _2(r)$$
Now write
$$u_1(r,z)=\tilde{u}_1(r,z)+\hat{u}_1(r,z)\hspace{4 mm}-l_1<z<0$$
$$u_2(r,z)=\tilde{u}_2(r,z)+\hat{u}_2(r,z)\hspace{4 mm}0<z<l_2$$

In order for $u_1$ and $u_2$ to satisfy the given boundary conditions,we require
$$\hat{u}_1\left(r,-l_1\right)=\hat{u}_2\left(r,l_2\right)=
   \hat{u}_1(a,z)=\hat{u}_2(a,
   z)=0,\hspace{4 mm}\hat{u}_1(r,0)=\hat{u}_2(r,0)\hspace{4 mm}$$
and $$k_1 \frac{\partial
   \hat{u}_1}{\partial z}\Bigr\rvert_{z = 0}-k_2
   \frac{\partial
   \hat{u}_2}{\partial z}\Bigr\rvert_{z = 0}=k_2
   \sigma _2(r)-k_1 \sigma
   _1(r)$$
Assume the following forms for $\hat{u}_1(r,z)$ and $\hat{u}_2(r,z)$
$$\hat{u}_1(r,z)=A_{10}+B_{10}
   z+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   J_0\left(\alpha _n r\right)
   \left(A_{1 n} \cosh
   \left(\alpha _n
   z\right)+B_{1 n} \sinh
   \left(\alpha _n
   z\right)\right)\hspace{4 mm}-l_1<z<0$$
$$\hat{u}_2(r,z)=A_{20}+B_{20}
   z+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   J_0\left(\alpha _n r\right)
   \left(A_{2 n} \cosh
   \left(\alpha _n
   z\right)+B_{2 n} \sinh
   \left(\alpha _n
   z\right)\right)\hspace{4 mm}0<z<l_2$$
Since $\hat{u}_1(a,z)=\hat{u}_2(a,z)=0,A_{10}=B_{10}=A_{20}=B_{20}=0$ and $\alpha _n=\frac{j_{0,n}}{a}$ where $j_{0,n}$ is the *n*th positive zero of $J_0(x).$ It follows that
$$\hat{u}_1\left(r,-l_1\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   J_0\left(\alpha _n r\right)
   \left(A_{1 n} \cosh
   \left(\alpha _n
   l_1\right)-B_{1 n} \sinh
   \left(\alpha _n
   l_1\right)\right)=0$$
Hence $A_{1 n}=B_{1 n} \tanh
   \left(\alpha _n l_1\right)$. Similarly, since $\hat{u}_2\left(r,l_2\right)=0,A_{2 n}=-B_{2 n} \tanh
   \left(\alpha _n l_2\right).$ Thus we have the series expansions
$$\hat{u}_1(r,z)=\sum
   _{n=1}^{\infty } B_{1 n}
   J_0\left(\alpha _n r\right)
   \left(\tanh \left(\alpha _n
   l_1\right) \cosh
   \left(\alpha _n
   z\right)+\sinh \left(\alpha
   _n z\right)\right)$$
$$\hat{u}_2(r,z)=\sum
   _{n=1}^{\infty } B_{2 n}
   J_0\left(\alpha _n r\right)
   \left(\sinh \left(\alpha _n
   z\right)-\tanh \left(\alpha
   _n l_2\right) \cosh
   \left(\alpha _n
   z\right)\right)$$
It now follows from the continuity condition $\hat{u}_1(r,0)=\hat{u}_2(r,0)$ that $B_{1 n}=-B_{2 n} \tanh
   \left(\alpha _n l_2\right)
   \coth \left(\alpha _n
   l_1\right)$
Finally the heat flux continuity condition lead to the equation
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } B_{2 n}
   \alpha _n J_0\left(\alpha
   _n r\right) \left(k_1 \coth
   \left(\alpha _n l_1\right)
   \tanh \left(\alpha _n
   l_2\right)+k_2\right)=f(r)$$
where $f(r)=k_1 \sigma _1(r)-k_2
   \sigma _2(r).$ To determine the coefficients $B_{2 n},$ we recall the expansion formula for the Fourier-Bessel series
$$f(r)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } c_n
   J_0\left(\alpha _n r\right)$$
$$c_n=\frac{2 \int_0^a r f(r)
   J_0\left(\alpha _n r\right)
   \, dr}{a^2
   J_1\left(j_{0,n}\right){}^2
   }$$
From which it follows that $B_{2 n}=\frac{c_n}{\alpha _n
   \left(k_1 \coth
   \left(\alpha _n l_1\right)
   \tanh \left(\alpha _n
   l_2\right)+k_2\right)}$